Can OAuth be used with SQL Linked Server (SF ODBC driver) for Authorization to Snowflake instead of username/password?
I see that with snowflake ODBC driver you can specify the authenticator as oauth and provide token for authZ. But I am trying to figure out when using the ODBC driver from snowflake for SQL linked Server configuration the driver supports Oauth instead of username and password authentication.
While configuring the System DSN I do see that the ODBC driver has option to specify Authenticator but there's no option to provide OAuth Token in the DSN. I was wondering if OAuth is not supported in Snowflake ODBC Driver with SQL Linked Server connections. Or I am missing some steps in the configuration.
